# Popup window needs to be closed before going back

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a link on a page on clicking which I open a new window like a popup.
Now I would like the user to close it before he can go back to the old page. He should not be able to navigate to other tab before closing it. How would I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popup(url) {
        var width = 300;
        var height = 200;
        var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
        var top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
        var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
        params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
        params += ', directories=no';
        params += ', location=no';
        params += ', menubar=no';
        params += ', resizable=no';
        params += ', scrollbars=no';
        params += ', status=no';
        params += ', toolbar=no';
        newwin = window.open(url, 'windowname5', params);
        if (window.focus) {
            newwin.focus()
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="popup('popup.html')">Centered popup window</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your window as a modal window, window.showModalDialog.

Look at the following instructions [showModalDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.showModalDialog)

An alternate way is to use jQuery dialog. in this case the whole screen is blocked and user can not do anything until dialog is closed. see [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

Create Close button in your popup.html page then close a window.

```
<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="window.close()">
```

thank u..